# How to get a list of the recipes applied to Chef node?

Tags: chef-infra

I want to know if a given recipe has been applied to a list of N nodes managed to Chef. How can I do this easily.

Comment: i don't understand why this was closed as too broad.  this is a perfectly clear question imo.

Answer (score 6):

You can accomplish this easily using knife (knife is your friend!).

To get a list of all of your nodes:

```
knife node list
```

To get a list of all of your nodes in a given environment:

```
knife node list --environment <ENVIRONMENT>
```

With a list of nodes in hand, you can then display details for a node using:

```
knife node show <NODE_ID>
```

A knife node show, will display:

```
Node Name:   
Environment: 
FQDN:        
IP:          
Run List:    
Roles:       
Recipes:     
Platform:    
Tags:
```

The *Recipes:* line is a list of the recipes which have been applied to a node.

Using *knife search* you can search for a set of nodes which meet specific criteria. Using it, you could find nodes that do or don't have a specific recipe applied to them.

Answer (score 6):

I suspect you're looking for something like this:

```
knife search node "recipes:<recipe_name>"
```

This will apply for explicit run lists as well as expanded (implicit) run lists.

There is more detailed documentation on knife searches here:

http://docs.opscode.com/knife_search.html

Comment: I found that neither `knife search node 'recipes:my_cookbook'` nor `knife search node 'recipes:my_cookbook::default'` was sufficient.  `knife search node 'recipes:my_cookbook\:\:default'` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean inside a recipe, You can use [search](https://docs.chef.io/chef_search.html), for example

```
ruby_nodes = search(:node, "recipes:ruby_build")
```

In order to achieve your actual question, you could do something like:

```
['192.168.1.2'].include?(ruby_nodes.map{|node| node[:ipaddress]})
```